# REST API - Swagger + Java + Jersey wrong listing path and additional apis

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty, swagger

In my project I am using Maven, Jetty, Swagger, Java and Jersey for creating REST API.
I also use Swagger to create nice-looking documentation for my API.

Almost everything is ok instead three issues.
At the first - this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.pjdb.rest;com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs;</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/rest</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Bootstrap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.pjdb.rest.Bootstrap</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.pjdb.rest.utils.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

1) How to remove api-docs from the beginnig of listingPath?

```
{
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.1",
  "basePath": "http://localhost:8080/rest",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/resources",
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/employee",
      "description": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to remove /api-docs at the beginning of the path..

2) How can I remove "/api-docs/resources" from apis? I use only 'employee' class, not 'resources'.

3) If I type `http://localhost:8080/rest/api-docs/employee` I have my methods
and '/' main URL which is empty. Can I remove it?

I've tried a lot of configurations. Am I missed something?

Comment: How about accept some answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this in this way:

1. Save api-docs.json generated by Swagger to hard-drive
2. Edit generated JSON as you need
3. Copy this file to `~/src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/api-docs.json`
4. Put `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/api-docs.json` to your discoveryUrl path in `index.html` of you `/swagger-ui` directory

This method needs from you, that you have to modify by yourself you main listing
if anything change but it's safe and working solution.

My api-docs.json looks like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "1.0",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.1",
    "basePath": "http://localhost:8080/rest",
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/api-docs.json/employee",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

and `swagger-ui/index.html` settings

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            discoveryUrl:"http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/api-docs.json",
            apiKey:"special-key",
            dom_id:"swagger-ui-container",
            supportHeaderParams: false,
            supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put'],
            onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
                if(console) {
                    console.log("Loaded SwaggerUI")
                    console.log(swaggerApi);
                    console.log(swaggerUi);
                }
              $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
            },
            onFailure: function(data) {
                if(console) {
                    console.log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
            docExpansion: "none"
        });

        window.swaggerUi.load();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer all three of your questions, although I'm hardly a Swagger expert. I'd also suggest talking to the Swagger devs on IRC, too- they're very quick to respond. I think it's worth getting Swagger to work "automatically" so that you don't have to manually update it- that seems less than optimal to me.

1) You don't want to get rid of *api-docs* in your listing path- you want some sort of unique name for your listings. It doesn't have to be *api-docs* - for example, I use *resources* - but you'll need some sort of prefix to differentiate between your actual REST resources and their descriptions, on Swagger. So I don't think this is a problem at all.

2) Did you have a class that extends *com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.JavaApiListing*, perhaps called *ApiResourceListing*.  That's where you determine the entry point to the Swagger docs. Maybe you had an extra class like this one which was pointing to */resources*? (It might also be an extension of *import com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListing*, which is what you use if you're not using a format suffix in your REST addresses.

3) I don't know about this one. Like I said in the beginning, maybe ask the Swagger guys on their IRC or their [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/swagger-swaggersocket).

4) This answer is relevant for Swagger 1.2. If you've just encountered this question recently, you might want to check out the [Swagger Jax-RS tutorial](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart), which has been updated for version 1.3.

Comment: This is the right answer. I had the same problem and changing the base class from JavaApiListing to ApiListing solved the problem!